# T-SQL: Move rows from one table to another, log both source and destination primary keys

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I feel like I know most of how to do this, just not how to join it up.

I'll try to break this down reasonably:

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestA] ([PrimaryKey] [int],[TestVal] [int]);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestB] ([PrimaryKey] [int],[TestVal] [int]);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Audit] ([PrimaryKey] [int],[SourcePrimaryKey] [int],[DestinationPrimaryKey] [int]);
```

I put values into TestA:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestA] ([TestVal]) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

Now, when I move rows (actually just the TestVal column values) from TestA into TestB, I want to add a row to Audit which contains the primary key from A, along with the corresponding primary key in B (where the value is going) -- then delete the row in A. Here's what I have:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @pk TABLE (b int);
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestB] ([TestVal])
        OUTPUT INSERTED.PrimaryKey INTO @pk
        SELECT TestVal FROM TestA WHERE TestVal > 2;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Audit] ([SourcePrimaryKey]) SELECT PrimaryKey FROM TestA WHERE TestVal > 2;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Audit] ([DestinationPrimaryKey]) SELECT b FROM @pk;
    DELETE FROM TestA WHERE TestVal > 2;
COMMIT
```

So I've created this temporary table, @pk, which accurately gets the destination primary keys (as they wind up in b), but I can't figure out how to marry those up with the primary keys where they came from, in A. Reading on MSDN, the OUTPUT function does not necessarily go in order reliably, so I can't just assume that a SELECT primary key from testa where testval > 2 would produce the same order.

Any ideas?

Comment: IIRC, for something like this you'd have to use a MERGE statement (which allows you to output things not in the inserted/deleted values of an INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statement). For example `merge testb using testa on 1 = 2 when not matched by target then insert(testval) values (testa.testval) output inserted.primarykey, testa.primarykey into @pk(bkey, akey);`

Comment: How do I set the conditions with that?

Comment: Assuming you used that method, you'd do something like `...when not matched by target AND testa.testval > 2 then insert...` For more complex queries it might become too difficult to manage and might be easier to do, say, the first method suggested in the answer provided.

Comment: Yours is perfect, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but can you tell me about the "on 1 = 2" part? Is that just some implicit reference I'm missing?

Comment: In brief, it's essentially shorthand to make sure there's never a match (`when not matched` will always be true because 1 does not equal 2, thus pulling every row from the source table and making it behave like an insert). You could use any condition that wouldn't match on the target table, really. You'd want to do this, if, say, table B wasn't empty and you wanted to pull every row from table A regardless.

Comment: Clever :) 
Thanks for that, I've learned something useful here!

Comment: will you have more then the number of columns provided in both tables?

Comment: Yeah, about 2 dozen or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: *I haven't evaluated MERGE method for this question... but I don't like MERGE for very large data sets as it's not performing well in most cases (compared to separate DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE, especially for columnstore indexes). So I'll suggest other methods.*

Method 1 (Simple). You can add SourcePK INT to TestB table and populate it at INSERT. Then in output you populate Audit table with SourcePK and TargetPK, and you don't need temp table.

Method 2 (Bad). If you can't add 2nd column into TestB, but you can change the data type of TestVal from INT to BIGINT, then you can use bitwise shift and bitwise OR/AND to save SourcePK inside TestVal. Then for every usage of TestVal you need to use only a half of its bits. I don't like this method, so it's better to implement (1)

Method 3 (Use with caution). You can generate the list of PKs for a target table and map it to each SourceID. You don't need OUTPUT as you just execute second INSERT into Audit with mapped SourceID/TargetID. But you need to make sure there are no concurrent processes that insert the data into the target table. Even with concurrency there are workarounds - you can reseed identity, and insert your range with SET IDENTITY_INSERT or use some locking mechanisms

Comment: Hmm, it will wind up being a fairly sizable dataset. I don't much like adding the column where it has no use after the procedure, but you're right, it will be a lot easier that way. Perhaps easier to trace errors, as well.

Comment: Having supplimentary columns for performance reasons is common practice. And you always have an option to add a column just before procedure and remove it after

Answer (score 0):

```
--Create tables
DECLARE @TestA TABLE
([PrimaryKey] INT IDENTITY,
 [TestVal]    INT
);
DECLARE @TestB TABLE
([PrimaryKey] INT IDENTITY,
 [TestVal]    INT
);
DECLARE @Audit TABLE
([PrimaryKey]            INT IDENTITY,
 [SourcePrimaryKey]      INT,
 [DestinationPrimaryKey] INT
);

--Insert Values
INSERT INTO @TestA([TestVal])
VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5);

--Temp table to hold key values
DECLARE @pk TABLE(b INT);

--Insert into TestB
INSERT INTO @testB(TestVal)
OUTPUT inserted.PrimaryKey
       INTO @pk
       SELECT TestVal
       FROM @testA ta
       WHERE ta.testVal > 2;

--Display what we have so far
SELECT *
FROM @TestA;
SELECT *
FROM @TestB;
SELECT *
FROM @pk;

--Insert into audit table
INSERT INTO @Audit
(SourcePrimaryKey,
 DestinationPrimaryKey
)
       SELECT ta.PrimaryKey,
              tb.PrimaryKey
       FROM @TestB tb
            JOIN @PK pk ON tb.PrimaryKey = pk.b
            JOIN @TestA ta ON tb.TestVal = ta.TestVal;  --Is test value always going to be Unque?
--Delete from testA table
DELETE FROM @TestA
WHERE TestVal IN(SELECT TestVal
                 FROM @TestB tb
                      JOIN @PK pk ON tb.PrimaryKey = pk.b);

--Display what we have 
SELECT *
FROM @TestA;
SELECT *
FROM @TestB;
SELECT *
FROM @pk;
```

Comment: I doubt TestVal is unique... otherwise why do we need PK then?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking down this route, but uniqueness is not certain.